# Massive whitespace in data cells is causing an issue

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have heaps of white space in my excel data. I tried the Trim Function but no good... can anyone help?
Thanks

(Modified) Example here below.....
"

```
<li>Elastic Sizing Band with 5 - 6cm Brim</li>



<li>3 Sizes



- (#4131 54cm to 50cm:::#4132 50cm-46cm:::#4133 58cm-54cm)</li>



<li>Rear Toggle Adjustment</li>


<li>Popular choice for schools and kindergartens </li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something along the lines of:

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"")`

to remove line breaks from the text in cell A1. `CHAR(10)` represents the line break.

Or to convert line breaks to spaces, you can use:

`=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)," "))`

The TRIM function in this case helps to reduce multiple line breaks to a single space.

Comment: Thanks... I tried that way but got stuck...I ended up using the Clean function, then the Trim function. It all seemed to be ok now.Thank you for your response